# Istanbul.js Fails At Cover Time With AMD Modules

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, istanbul

I writting an app using Backbone/Marionette and RequireJS with AMD-style modules and I trying to add a coverage step to it, but, when running `istanbul cover myTestFile.js`, istanbul throws this error:

> __cov_EsyvGtIcLKP7TgjU5WMSQw.s['1']++;define(function(require){__cov_EsyvGtIcL
>   `define is not defined`

I don't how to fix this as I've never done coverage for browser side code and this is my first time using AMD style module.

Istanbul also says a coverage report was written, so I don't understand if that means that it actually ran successfully or not.

Any pointers would be of great help. Here's the complete output of the `istanbul cover mytestfile.js` command (with some detauls changed):

```
=============================================================================
Writing coverage object [/Users/myuser/src/myapp/coverage/coverage.json]
Writing coverage reports at [/Users/myuser/src/myapp/coverage]
=============================================================================

=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : 5% ( 1/20 )
Branches     : 0% ( 0/2 )
Functions    : 0% ( 0/5 )
Lines        : 5% ( 1/20 )
================================================================================
/Users/myuser/src/myapp/app/myapp/app-collection.js:9
__cov_EsyvGtIcLKP7TgjU5WMSQw.s['1']++;define(function(require){__cov_EsyvGtIcL
                                      ^
ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mysuser/src/myapp/app/myapp/app-collection.js:9:39)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/istanbul/lib/hook.js:107:24)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/myuser/src/myapp/test/specs/applications-tests.js:9:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

Comment: The `istanbul cover test.js` runs the test script in *Node*, which is very different than running in the browser, where it is supposed to run. Take a look at [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io).

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos Ended up using Karma. A couple of hours setting up the config for RequireJS with Karma was enough to have it working